# If loop in 'Then' statement of Case statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I wanted to use **if** condition in **Then** statement of **Case** statement in SQL Server 2008. How to use it?

Comment: Note that an `IF` has no result, it's not an expression. This is why the answers here suggest (rightfully so) to use a nested `CASE` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Then` keyword [Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement like follows in Sql server

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN TestRowValue = 'R' THEN
              Case When TestColumn = 'P' THEN 'Road'
              ELSE 'Board'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
      END,
   Name
FROM Production.Product
```

Answer (score 2):

Nest them

```
CASE
   WHEN foo = 'bar' THEN 
              CASE
                 WHEN black = 'white' THEN .. 
                 WHEN W = 'TF' THEN ... 
                 ELSE
              END
   WHEN fish = 'bicycle' THEN ... 
   ELSE ... 
END
```